# gesture recognizer is not working on subview

Tags: ios, uiview, touch

I have a `UIView` which has a `UILabel` view as a subview. Now I have added gesture for self (which is UIView). UIView recognizes the touch but subview(UILabel) doesn't.

There are similar questions in stackoverflow which tells the below property to set YES. I tried but it doesn't solve.

I have also set `label.userInteractionEnabled = YES.`

Comment: Posting some code might help.

Comment: Hi all, It's my bad. In subview class there is a piece of code to handle not to recognize the touch. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
  if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
  {
    return YES;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

You may need to set the delegate of gesture recognizer as self